# I can't seem to access my Auth inside a vendor package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I had a Laravel app that I created, then I added another Laravel package for Oauth2 for a CRM.

This created a vendor and migration for DB. I tested it and it worked, I authenticated my CRM.

Now I would like to have that record be tied to the **user_id** in the Auth scaffold that I created with `composer make:auth`

However, when I try to get the current user from inside of those vendor files, it is not pulling in that information and is giving me errors.

I think this may be a namespace issue, but maybe it could be a guard or middleware. I am not sure. I am pretty laravel

I have tried a handful of other solutions, but I wasn't sure if those were tied to my specific issue

```
<?php

namespace Djaxho\LaravelInfusionsoftOauth2\Http\Controllers;
//namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Djaxho\LaravelInfusionsoftOauth2\Infusionsoft;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class AuthorizeInfusionsoftApiController extends BaseController
'''

print Auth::user()->id;
```

I see that it is in its own namespace, is this what is the issue, laravel is not looking outside?

I get this error:

> Class 'Djaxho\LaravelInfusionsoftOauth2\Http\Controllers\Auth' not
>   found

Answer (score 0):

Their page says it pretty straightforward on what to do.

https://packagist.org/packages/djaxho/laravel-infusionsoft-oauth2

> Installation (These instructions are for an 'alerady set-up' laravel
>   project with a functioning database set up) Add the service provider
>   for laravel by adding the following line to your 'providers' array in
>   the file congig/app.php
>
> Djaxho\LaravelInfusionsoftOauth2\LaravelInfusionsoftOauth2ServiceProvider::class,

And add

```
use Djaxho\LaravelInfusionsoftOauth2\Infusionsoft;
```

to your model where you are calling the auth from.

That being said, I dont know if this package handles auth seperately or doesnt. In that case you should use the laravel facade,

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth
```

Comment: Yeah it does seem pretty straight forward, thats why I chose it. Getting it set up was easy.
I have used the use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth in the file but that does not work either. I also use use Djaxho\LaravelInfusionsoftOauth2\Infusionsoft;

I would like to add the user_id to the array when it is sent to the DB. And those pages use the namespace Djaxho\LaravelInfusionsoftOauth2\Http\Controllers;

I thought including use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth should fix it but it does not

Comment: What do you get after adding Auth facade and then trying Auth::user()?

Comment: just a blank page

It is like this is a laravel app within a laravel app, if I navigate to my basic crud app I can pull the info easily, but any of the pages/ views for this package dont seem to see anything there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give you routes in your package `web` middleware  and it will works fine
.

Comment: I was wondering if it was a middleware issue, I will test that out